# How to score arbitrary sentences based on how likely they are to occur in the real world?

Tags: neural-network, rnn

According to article about LSTM [here](http://www.wildml.com/2015/09/recurrent-neural-networks-tutorial-part-1-introduction-to-rnns/), I know that:

> it allows us to score arbitrary sentences based on how likely they are to occur in the real world. This gives us a measure of grammatical and semantic correctness. Such models are typically used as part of Machine Translation systems.

But, it seems that this article doesn't point out how to compute the score with `LSTM`.

Any way to compute the score?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically you would use a [perplexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perplexity) value. For example, if your LSTM model is word-based and you have a sentence $[x_1, x_2 . . . x_N]$, and your model predicts the words that appear in that sentence with probability $p(x_i|x_0..x_{i-1})$ (where $x_0$ is a "start token" or whatever you use to start your RNN prediction sequence). Then you might quote a per-word perplexity for that sentence under your model as

### $- \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N log_2(p(x_i|x_0..x_{i-1}))$

Using an LSTM to predict consecutive words, it is practical to construct an array of probabilities $[p_1, p_2 . . . p_N]$ by running the network on the sentence and noting the probabilities for the correct matching word - i.e. $p_i = $ the predicted probability of the correct class $x_i$ at each step, which simplifies the expression:

### $- \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N log_2(p_i)$

Comment: sorry, I have a stupid question, how cound I get $[p_1, p_2 . . . p_N]$ ? I find a `LSTM` implementation, its `next_word_probs` is a matrix(see [here](https://github.com/dennybritz/rnn-tutorial-gru-lstm/blob/master/utils.py#L160)). Or you mean `perplexity` like [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py#L376)

Comment: The matrix is the probability for every word on each time step, you need the probability of the word from the sentence you are scoring (you should have a way to convert words to indexes, and you know the time step, so this is just an index lookup). Yes the `test_perplexity` is likely to be a similar measure to that given in my answer - there are a few different ways to do it, so might not be 100% same value, but if you can evaluate your target sentence using the same test code, then that should be equally good for you to score your sentence, and would save you effort to implement it.